# Copy an application over to another phone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications

I have a very old demo application on my iPhone. It was on the app store a long time ago (1 year) the guy who developed it works with me. He's since taken the app off iTunes, however our boss wants to demo it tomorrow. Anyone know how I can go about getting the application onto his phone bearing in mind the following:

- We can't deploy from the developer's computer
- It's not on iTunes

Comment: are you willing to jailbreak both phones?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy it, because it won't match the profiles.

Your only hope is use a provisioning profile and set your boss' phone as a development device

Here's [how](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

I did a blogpost which details how you can copy an application from one iPhone to another. Not sure if it's an exact fit with the constraints you have placed but still worth a try. Here's the link- http://www.gauravgupta.in/blog/2009/08/share-iphone-apps-with-multiple-iphones/